# Baby Rudin 10.11 and 10.12

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, differential-forms

These are definitions which we need for the question
[image]

[image]

let $y$ be a $1$-surface ( a curve of class $\mathscr C'$) in $R^3$, with parameter domain $[0,1]$.

write ($x,y,z$)in place of ($x_1,x_2,x_3$), and put

$\omega$ = $xdy$ + $ydx$.

then
$\int_y$ $\omega$ = $\int_0^1$ [$y_1(t)y_2'(t) + y_2(t)y_1'(t)$]$dt$ ( mark this by ($\star$)) = $y_1(1)y_2(1)$ - $y_1(0)y_2(0)$ ( mark this by ($\ast$)).

what do we mean in the notation $a_{{i_1}...i_k}$ ? is it the product of functions $a_{i_1}...a_{i_k}$ or it's part of the index ? ( definition 10.11).

and the chief question :

I don't understand why is $\int_y$ $\omega$ equal of ($\star$)  and hereby I also don't understand why is ($\star$) equal of ($\ast$)

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Rudin is not the best place to be learning differential forms and related material. In the meantime, you might find some of my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile,  helpful (the latter half of MATH 3510).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On RHS of
$$
\omega = \sum_{i_1,\dots, i_k = 1}^n a_{i_1\dots i_k}(x) dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_k} \tag{34}
$$
the sum is meant to be over all indices $i_1\dots i_k$, each of which runs from $1$ to $n$. Later in the text, he restricts them to be such that $1 \le i_1 < \dots < i_k \le n $ with the standard presentation. The set $\{a_{i_1\dots i_k}\}$ is a *set of functions, indexed as above*.

So for your $\gamma: [0,1] \to E \subset \mathbb R^3$, and we have $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t),\gamma_3(t)) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ and the jacobians are $\{\frac{\partial \gamma_1}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \gamma_2}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \gamma_3}{\partial t}\}$ or $\{x'(t), y'(t), z'(t)\}$ , you can compute them as described below. Now with $\omega = xdy + ydx$, we have $a_1(x,y,z) = y, a_2(x,y,z) = x$ and $a_3(x,y,z) = 0$ and with $(35)$ we get
$$
\omega(\gamma) \equiv \int_\gamma \omega = \int_{[0,1]}\sum_{j = 1}^3a_j(\gamma(t))\gamma_j'(t)dt = \int_{[0,1]} (\gamma_1(t)\gamma_2'(t) + \gamma_2(t)\gamma_1'(t))dt\\
= \int_{[0,1]} (x(t)y'(t) + y(t)x'(t))dt
$$

Now for the intergal you know, I hope, the product rule $(f(t) g(t))' = f'(t) g(t) + f(t) g'(t)$ that shouold explain how you get the equality. Then
$$
\int_a^b f'(t) g(t) + f(t) g'(t) dt = f(b) g(b) - f(a) g(a)
$$

---

**Appendix:**

The differential form (in Rudin's book) is a map $\omega : \mathscr{C}'(D,E) \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\omega : \Phi \mapsto \omega(\Phi) \equiv \int_\Phi \omega := \int_D \sum a_{i_1\dots i_k}(\Phi(u)) \frac{\partial (x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dots, u_k)} d u \tag{35}
$$
(where $\mathscr{C}'(D,E)$ is a set not a vector space!). The symbols $a_{i_1\dots i_k}$ are indexed functions $a_{i_1\dots i_k}:\mathbb R^n \supset E \to \mathbb R$, they can be precomposed with $\Phi:D \to E$ to get $a_{i_1\dots i_k} \circ \Phi:D \to \mathbb R$.

The Notation
$$
\frac{\partial (x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dots, u_k)}
$$
denotes certain determinants from the jacobian of the $k$-surface $\Phi$, *not the absolute value of them since it is a signed integral*. More explicitly we have
$$
\Phi: D \ni (u_1,\dots, u_k) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in E.
$$
and its jacobian is the $(n\times k)$-matrix
$$
D\Phi = \begin{pmatrix}
\partial x_1 / \partial u_1 & \dots  & \partial x_1 / \partial u_k \\
\vdots                      & \ddots &  \vdots \\
\partial x_n / \partial u_1 & \dots  &   \partial x_n / \partial u_k \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By taking only the $k$ rows $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ we have a restriction (or projection $P_I$, with $I = (i_1,\dots, i_k)$ on) to a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, and the jacobian $D(P_I \circ \Phi)$ of the composition $P_I \circ \Phi : D \to P_I(E) \subset \mathbb R^k$ is then a (square) $(k\times k)$-matrix, of which one can take the determinant, that is
$$
\frac{\partial (x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dots, u_k)} = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial x_{i_1} / \partial u_1 & \dots  & \partial x_{i_1} / \partial u_k \\
\vdots                      & \ddots &  \vdots \\
\partial x_{i_k} / \partial u_1 & \dots  &   \partial x_{i_k} / \partial u_k \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Well read it in the pictures you uploaded, after equation $(35)$, the $\phi_j$ to $\Phi$ are as $\gamma_j$ to $\gamma$,..and these are $\gamma$s, stop writing $y$s. All your questions are answered exactly there