# Question on baby Rudin examples 10.12

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I have two questions:

$(a)$.

Fix $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ and define $\gamma(t) = (a\cos(t),b\sin(t))$ where  $(0\leq t \leq 2\pi)$. So that $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $R^2$. (Its range is an ellipse.)

Then

$$\int_\gamma x dy = \int_0^{2\pi} ab \cos^2(t)dt = \pi ab \tag{1}$$

$(b)$.

Let $D$ be the $3$-call defined by $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \varphi \leq 2\pi$. Define $\phi ( r,\theta,\varphi ) = (x,y,z)$, where $x = r\sin\theta \cos\varphi$, $y = r\sin\theta \sin\varphi$, $z = r\cos\theta$

Then
$$
J_\phi (r,\theta,\varphi) = \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\varphi)} =  r^2\sin\theta.
$$

Hence
$$
\int_{\phi} dx \land dy \land dz = \int_D J_\phi\ \color{red}{dr\,d\theta\, d\varphi} = \frac{4\pi}{3}. \tag{2}
$$

I don't understand how do we get $(1)$ and $(2)$ .

(in the $(2)$ I also don't understand why is $\int_D J_{\phi}$ equal of $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ ).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this for (1) & (2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337530/baby-rudin-10-11-and-10-12/4337538#4337538 Focus on the answer there

Comment: So for (b) you have $a(\Phi(u)) = 1$ and $J_\phi$ is actually the determinant of the Jacobian matrix $D\Phi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) the 1-surface $\gamma$ gives the determinants as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\gamma_1(t)}{\partial t} &= \partial(a\cos t)/\partial t = - a \sin t
& \frac{\partial\gamma_2(t)}{\partial t} &= \partial(b\sin t)/\partial t = b \cos t \\
\end{align}
The 1-form we have is $\omega = x dy$, i.e.
\begin{align}
a_1(\gamma(t)) &= 0 & 
a_2(\gamma(t)) &=x(t) = \gamma_1(t) = a \cos(t) 
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\omega(\gamma) = \int_\gamma \omega = \int_{[0,2\pi]}(a_1(\gamma(t))\frac{\partial\gamma_1(t)}{\partial t} + a_2(\gamma(t))\frac{\partial\gamma_2(t)}{\partial t}) dt = \dots
$$

For (b) we have $\omega = dx \land dy \land dz$ and so $a(x,y,z) = 1$
$$
\int_{\phi} dx \land dy \land dz = \int_D J_\phi\ \color{red}{dr\,d\theta\, d\varphi} = \int_{r = 0}^1 \int_{\theta = 0}^\pi \int_{\varphi= 0}^{2\pi} r^2\sin\theta dr\,d\theta\, d\varphi \\
= \dots
$$
For your other question look at the Appendix in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337530/baby-rudin-10-11-and-10-12?noredirect=1&lq=1) to learn how you get the
$$\frac{\partial (x_{i_1},\dots,x_{i_k})}{\partial (u_1,\dots, u_k)}$$ from $\Phi$.